# Set a variable once at the start of a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, for-loop

So if I have a `for (let item of items)` loop, is there a way to track an iterator as well? I have a fairly complex loop of this type and I would like to have an iterator that starts at 0 at the beginning of the for loop. I know `for(let i=0;...` would track the way I wanted but the loop for my case does not iterate in a way that is easy to track that way hence why I'm using a `for (let item of items)` loop. Setting the value before the loop starts is not an option as the for loop exists in a `Subscription`.

Comment: Actually I found another solution not involving this which is particular to my use case but I'll leave the question open.

Comment: What does your `items` array look like?

Comment: It's a `pair` of classes.

Comment: Ok thanks @zfrisch that is a solution. I was actually able to solve this with the for loop in place. Accessing information about the item number. I was just wondering if there was some sort of `static` variable declaration system in JS that might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MDN article for [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
const obj = { a: 5, b: 7, c: 9 };
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
}
```

It also works if the object is an array:

```
const arr = [ 5, 7, 9 ];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "0 5", "1 7", "2 9"
}
```

Comment: I need the index, not a key value pair.

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz If the object is an array, then the key is the index. I edited the answer.

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz No problem :)